# New column in panda, Reincremental based on value

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I want to create a new column in panda where the order is incremental if title column is the same as previous row.  If title is different, restart the count.

How can I do this?

```
original_df
title
music
music
theatre
theatre
theatre

update_df
order     title
1         music
2         music
1         theatre
2         theatre
3         theatre
```

Comment: try this ```df['order'] = df.groupby('title').cumcount()+1```

Comment: Yes I can use this.  Thank you very much!